# Button get specific input hidden value JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, select

I have a table in which the information is generated automatically
for each line I have a button which in turn has an input type = 'hidden' element:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_1" value="1" />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="bttn_1">DEL</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_2" value="2" />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="bttn_2">DEL</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW3</td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_3" value="3" />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="bttn_3">DEL</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I press button 3 from the bttn_3 id then I can take the value from the hidden input with the id_3 id.

Comment: Where is your code where you take the value from the hidden input? Or do you want us to code it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('button[id^=bttn_]').click(function() {
  var val = $(this).siblings("input").val()
})
```

`$('button[id^=bttn_]')` will select all buttons where the `id` starts with `bttn_`

`$(this).prev("input")` means that we will select the input that is associated with the button clicked.

**Demo**

```js
$('button[id^=bttn_]').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).siblings("input").val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_1" value="1" />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="bttn_1">DEL</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_2" value="2" />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="bttn_2">DEL</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW3</td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="id_3" value="3" />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="bttn_3">DEL</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```